# i want to load next page with having same nav and panel as previous page have.

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to load another page in same page with having all the function of current page.
For example i have page which have "navigation bar" "panel" , now what i want is next page should get load but only content gets change.not the whole page .

Answer (score 0):

you should devid you page as ... (1) Header , (2) Main sections , (3) Footer

and include them using php include file  examble >>>  `include 'filename';`

[check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

So you have the same ( Header page ) and ( Footer page )

But only the Content page is changing

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

//only change this for the other pages

include 'main.php';

include 'footer';
?>
```